# How do I reassign base class attributes from a base class instance without losing derived attributes?

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
class Base{
    private:
        int general_attribute;
};

class Derived : public Base{
    private:
        int specific attribute;

    public:
        void reassign(Base value);
};
```

Is there a general, maintainable way in which I can write `reassign` such that only the base class members (i.e. `general_attribute`) will be copied from the base-class instance?

If I understand correctly, writing

```
void Derived::reassign(Base value){
     *this = value;
}
```

won't do because it will result in the loss of `specific_attribute` because of object slicing.

What are some recommended solutions?

Comment: What you wrote won't affect the derived members, they are unknown to `Base::operator =`.

Comment: `this->Base::operator=(value);`

Comment: @yurikilochek Thank you!